# Creating iPhone style bubble list view in android

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a chat application the interacts between two users. I want to show the interaction between the users in the form of a iPhone bubble list view...

I found a tutorial that shows to create a bubble list in IOS... [Here's the link...](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps)...

I have seen lot of Android applications that display the bubble list view like Handcent sms etc. I am also sure that some developers here may have a clue about doing it... I would be grateful if any one direct me towards a tutorial or some samples of achieving the task...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [something like this](http://www.sheikhaman.com/ProjectDetails.php?pid=2)?

Click on the screen shots.

that is a twitter application that presents tweets in a bubble like format.

You'll have to implement a custom adapter for you ListView, where inside the getView() method, you can control how each row is drawn.

Implement different custom layouts for even-odd rows and you can something like this.

**EDIT**: You can find a full tutorial here: http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-tutorial-custom-adapter-for.html

Comment: This was what i am looking for... Can u share any tutorials or some of the code of how to achieve this. Sorry to ask because i m newbie

Comment: Not a problem. I can share the code and the tutorial that I have made. But for that You'll have to wait a bit. I'll reach home send send you the whole code by tonight, if that's okay for you.

Comment: You'll have it by tonight, inshAllah :-)

Comment: You can find the full tutorial here: http://goo.gl/tUzNN

Sorry, I couldn't post it last night. my BSNL internet went down.. you know!

Comment: Check the date, @user31231234124

Comment: `Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());` this should work perfectly with Android, @Aman Alam