# How to visualize text in message field in android?

Tags: android

I would like show my text messages like this in picture that i have attached. Please give me some hints on that...

[image]

Sample text that i like to have:

Comment: Hello, your question is very vast. You should precise what you have already done and what is the thing you don't know (creating a list of content, have different text colors, apply a bubble effect, ...).

Comment: You will find help here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436165/creating-iphone-style-bubble-list-view-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454225/bubble-chat-issue-android-listview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023232/android-listview-style-like-text-messages-conversations

Comment: Also see this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode

Comment: -1 no research effort, not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would create a small empty speech balloon as a 9-patch. This will be used as your TextView background and will expand as necessary to encompass the text.  I guess you'll need to create one for every color you intend to use unless someone can tell me how to add color to such a thing.

Next, I would create a layout.xml file that contains some sort of container widget (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout probably) that holds a single TextView that occupies the left half of the container.  Make another that puts the TextView in the right half.

Inside the container, put a TextView that uses the above-mentioned 9-patch image as the background.

Then, I would use a ListView for the overall container for your text messages.  Construct an Adapter subclass that manages your list of text messages and uses a LayoutInflator to expand the above-mentioned layout.xml files to return the Views to be displayed by the ListView.

That's how I would do it anyway.  Implementation details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: +1 for "Implementation details are left as an exercise for the reader."